# read from csv, delete line based on first portion

Tags: java, swing, csv, io

In my app I am displaying the first portion of each line of the CSV in a JList, and when it is selected and a button is pressed (delete) I want it to remove that line from the file based on the first entry. I am trying the method where you have a temp file then write to it then rename it at the end but that isnt working out for some reason. Any ideas?

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    // Delete service
    String selected = (String) jList1.getSelectedValue();
    File passwords = new File("/users/aak7133/desktop/passwords.txt");
    File temp = new File("/users/aak7133/desktop/temp.txt");

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(passwords));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(temp));
        String line;
        System.out.println(selected);
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
            //String trimmedLine = line.trim();

            if (line.contains(selected)) {
                continue;
            }
            writer.write(line);
        }
        boolean successful = temp.renameTo(passwords);

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    updateList();
    clearFields();

}
```

Comment: Close your readers and writers

Comment: Doesnt have anything to do with my issue

Comment: @erp That's why it was only a comment - just good programming advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually caused by the open reader and writer. This should work:

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String selected = (String) jList1.getSelectedValue();
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try {
        File passwords = new File("/users/aak7133/desktop/passwords.txt");
        File temp = File.createTempFile("temp", ".txt", new File("/users/aak7133/desktop/"));
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(passwords));
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(temp));
        String line;
        System.out.println(selected);
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
            // String trimmedLine = line.trim();

            if (line.contains(selected)) {
                continue;
            }
            writer.write(line + "\n");
        }
        if (passwords.canWrite()) {
            try {
                reader.close();
                reader = null;
            } catch (IOException ignore) {}

            try {
                writer.close();
                writer = null;
            } catch (IOException ignore) {}

            String path = passwords.getAbsolutePath();
            passwords.delete();
            boolean successful = temp.renameTo(new File(path));
            System.out.println(successful);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException ignore) {}
        }
        if (writer != null) {
            try {
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException ignore) {}
        }
    }
     updateList();
     clearFields();
}
```

Comment: Didnt see your post before I did. It was just the delete.passwords I was missing. Thanks for the reply m8

Answer (score 0):

I figured out I needed to put `passwords.delete()` before `temp.renameTo(passwords)`.  This fixed the issue right away.